# Does moving or renaming a executable file (in particular a Windows executable under Wine) impact its running while it is being run?

Tags: scripts, wine, executable

In Ubuntu,

- when running an executable file or a script file, if I move or rename the file, will the running be impacted?
- when running a Windows executable (e.g. [PDFXCview.exe](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer)) under wine, will moving or renaming the Windows executable file impact its running under wine?

Thanks.

Comment: No. It's perfectly OK to move (delete) running executables. See https://askubuntu.com/q/814210/504066 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1712033/5830574.

Comment: For `ELF` files that are loaded into memory, no effect. However, for `#!interpreter` scripts, it depends entirely on the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

## Are airplanes always refueled on the ground?

Well of course you think. But .001% of the time they are refueled in mid-air. Military applications for example. So the rule isn't steadfast. The same is true with executable files and scripts. Viruses for example infect executables while they are running and the copy on disk as well. That's a good thing if they break. However non-viruses also can update executables / scripts.

## Example of script that updates itself

This script: [How can I cause a script to log in a separate file the number of times it has been executed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988032/how-can-i-cause-a-script-to-log-in-a-separate-file-the-number-of-times-it-has-be/1015648#1015648) updates itself with the number of times it has been run.

Conventionally a separate configuration file is used for each script file to record how many times it is run. But if you have dozens upon dozens of scripts it makes sense to store the run count in the script itself. Additionally, you don't have to keep track of where the configuration file is stored and changing the script if the configuration file is moved. The code to modify the run count can be included with a `source` or `.` bash command to reduce maintenance costs and improve readability.

#### Code snippet

Here's the relevant code from the link above:

```bash
# This script run count: 0

[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@" || :
#     This is useful boilerplate code for shell scripts.  Put it at the top  of
#     the  shell script you want to lock and it'll automatically lock itself on
#     the first run.  If the env var $FLOCKER is not set to  the  shell  script
#     that  is being run, then execute flock and grab an exclusive non-blocking
#     lock (using the script itself as the lock file) before re-execing  itself
#     with  the right arguments.  It also sets the FLOCKER env var to the right
#     value so it doesn't run again.

# Read this script with entries separated newline " " into array
mapfile -t ScriptArr < "$0"

# Build search string that cannot be named
SearchStr="This script"
SearchStr=$SearchStr" run count: "

# Find our search string in array and increment count
for i in ${!ScriptArr[@]}; do
    if [[ ${ScriptArr[i]} = *"$SearchStr"* ]]; then
        OldCnt=$( echo ${ScriptArr[i]} | cut -d':' -f2 )
        NewCnt=$(( $OldCnt + 1 ))
        ScriptArr[i]=$SearchStr$NewCnt
        break
    fi
done

# Rewrite our script to disk with new run count
# BONUS: Date of script after writing will be last run time
printf "%s\n" "${ScriptArr[@]}" > "$0"
```

#### Breaking down the code

I'll quickly explain how the unique code parts works.

```bash
mapfile -t ScriptArr < "$0"
```

^ This reads the entire script `/script/path/script-name.sh` into the array named `ScriptArr`.

```bash
OldCnt=$( echo ${ScriptArr[i]} | cut -d':' -f2 )
NewCnt=$(( $OldCnt + 1 ))
ScriptArr[i]=$SearchStr$NewCnt
```

^ This takes the old count on the comment line: `# This script run count: 0` and increments it by 1.

```bash
printf "%s\n" "${ScriptArr[@]}" > "$0"
```

^ This writes the modified script array out to disk as the new executable script. A nice (or bad) side effect is the date the script was last run is now the scripts modification date.

## Multi-User considerations

Notice the `FLOCKER` variable from the command above:

```bash
[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@" || :
```

^ This is for multiple users. If one user is running the script it stops a second user from running the very same script. Let's say you wait until the first user's job ends and then move the script. That's bad because the second user that was in wait mode now gets access to run the script because the semaphore lock is dropped. However after the first user's job finished you moved the script to a different directory. Not a big deal 99.999% of the time but, it's the extremely rare times that are the unfathomable bugs.

## Summary

A running script or executable can change itself or can even be change another program that's no running within the same application.

Generally speaking it is 99% safe to move (ie rename) a program that is already running. That said I would never do that.

Your question is about `wine` (pseudo-Windows) but these bash scripts were designed for Ubuntu under Linux and Ubuntu under Windows (WSL). The point isn't so much about `wine` but to show what can be done in programming / scripting world.

Comment: Technically, I think you mean "pseudo". :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Occupational hazard from spelling `sudo` all the time ;)